# How to convert letters to binary code?

Tags: javascript

```
// # Write a method that takes in an integer `offset` and a string.
// # Produce a new string, where each letter is shifted by `offset`. You
// # may assume that the string contains only lowercase letters and
// # spaces.
// #
// # When shifting "z" by three letters, wrap around to the front of the
// # alphabet to produce the letter "c".
// #
// # You'll want to use String's `ord` method and Integer's `chr` method.
// # `ord` converts a letter to an ASCII number code. `chr` converts an
// # ASCII number code to a letter.
// #
// # You may look at the ASCII printable characters chart:
// #
// #     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters
// #
// # Notice that the letter 'a' has code 97, 'b' has code 98, etc., up to
// # 'z' having code 122.
// #
// # You may also want to use the `%` modulo operation to handle wrapping
// # of "z" to the front of the alphabet.
// #
// # Difficulty: hard. Because this problem relies on outside
// # information, we would not give it to you on the timed challenge. :-)
//
// def caesar_cipher(offset, string)
// end
//
// # These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
// # your solution, they should all print true.
//
// puts(
//   'caesar_cipher(3, "abc") == "def": ' +
//   (caesar_cipher(3, 'abc') == 'def').to_s
// )
// puts(
//   'caesar_cipher(3, "abc xyz") == "def abc": ' +
//   (caesar_cipher(3, 'abc xyz') == 'def abc').to_s
// )    



    function caesar_cipher(offset,string){
        var strSplit = string.split(" ");
        var result =[];
        var str = "";

         strSplit.forEach(function(word){
           for(var j=0;j<word.length;j++){
            result.push(word[j].charCodeAt(0)); // returns 65
           }
         });

         for(var idx =0;idx<result.length;idx++){
           if(result[idx] ===122 || (result[idx]+offset) ===122){
             str += String.fromCharCode((97+ offset));

           }else{
            str += String.fromCharCode((result[idx]+ offset));
           } 
         }
        return str;
        }
        console.log(caesar_cipher(3,"abc xyz"));
```

How can I get around a situation like this:
if the letter code is 121 and the offset is 3 which is equal to = 124;
How can I go wrap around to the front of the alphabet??

Comment: _"How can I go wrap around"_ Did you read the code comments? __// You may also want to use the `%` modulo operation to handle wrapping
// # of "z" to the front of the alphabet.__

Comment: how Can I do that?

Comment: It's good to don't rely on ASCII codes at all. Create an array with used alphabeth and use indexOf as a code. You'll automatically get any encodings support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can get the ascii-code of a character by doing

```
var asciiCode = "a".charCodeAt(0); //removing 0 will give the same output
```

Then you can add the offset to it

```
var newAsciiCode = asciiCode + 3; //3 is offset
```

then get your new letter back

```
var newLetter = String.fromCharCode( newAsciiCode );
```

Comment: true, but for a situation where you have: 122 + 3  = 125                              var newLetter = String.fromCharCode( 125 ) is === '}' but what I want is to wrap around that.

Answer (score 0):

The alphabets are used in JavaScrip as defined in ASCII. should do all the shifts as following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

where cases when you have 122 + your offset which will exceed the ASCII limit, so if you want to round that up to go back to the front of the ASCII:

just add 96 to your current (ASCII code % 122). It will around it back from 96-122.
for instance, imagine that the offset is 3; and your current letter ASCII code is 122; here it goes

(123 + 96) % 122 = 97 which is an "a"